Non trivial smooth extensions over a manifold?
Assume I have a smooth (Riemannian) manifold $M$ and a compact subset of that manifold $S$. Assume I have a function $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
I want to smoothly, "periodically" extend $f$ to the rest of the manifold. Now, the notion of periodicity on a manifold is weird, so let me try to define it.
The eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator provide a set of functions which I will say are "periodic" for the manifold. So "periodic" in this case means "it behaves like the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian". This concept is known as "Manifold harmonics".
If your manifold happens to be the real line, then if you apply the regular Fourier transform, you get a periodic function over $\mathbb{R}$. This is what I am trying to extend to arbitrary manifolds.
Here is an issue, however. Let's try doing the most naive approach:

Find the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian  $\phi_i$
Define an inner product $\langle, \rangle : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by restricting the inner product of the manifold to just $S$, i.e. $\int_{S} f \cdot g $. Or in english, the inner product is the integral of the product of the two functions over the subset $S$. Note that this is the same as defining one of your functions to be 0 outside of $S$.
Project $f$ over $\{\phi_i\}$ through the specialized inner product above and extract the coefficients $a_i$
Blend the eigenfunctions over the full manifold.

If you do the above approach, which feels similar to the 1D case, you actually end up with the exact same function $f$ you started with, rather than a "periodic" function. Because all you did was project a function into an orthonormal basis and then added the result back up.
I am wondering if someone could suggest a better way of extending the fourier technique I mentioned for the 1D case onto more generalized manifolds.
